# Positive triangle pulse in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to create a positive triangle pulse. I want to be able to define the amplitude, rise and fall time as well as the number points in them.
From the documentation of scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html), I found the 'sawtooth' wave form and I am trying to utilize it.

The problem I face is that, the said waveform, oscillates between 1,-1, but I want it to go from 0 till a specified positive limit. Here is an example of what I want to make:

[image]

This pulse will be use to correlate data from a detector, so it is important to be able to specify rise/fall time and the points in them, in order to experiment and get the best possible clarity out of it.

Can I manipulate the 'sawtooth' signal to get what I want? Or do I have to create the signal myself? If the only option is to create it, could I have some help as to how I could define it in python?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Add 1 (makes it go from 0 to 2) then multiply by (limit/2) - it will now go from 0 to limit.

Comment: That was very useful! Now I have to play with np.linspace to get the values I need and the phase to get the rise/fall time that best suits the data!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to use linear interpolation to build the wanted function. If you want a periodic pulse function, [numpy.interp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) has a `period` option in order to wrap the x-axis periodically. Otherwise, remove the argument, the function will remains 0 after the first pulse.

```
rise_duration = 1
fall_duration = 3
period = 6

control_points_x = [0, rise_duration, rise_duration+fall_duration]
control_points_y = [0, 1, 0]

x = np.linspace(0, 14, 123)
triangular_pulses = np.interp(x, control_points_x, control_points_y, period=period)

# Graph
plt.plot(x, triangular_pulses, label='interpolation');
plt.plot(control_points_x, control_points_y, 'ok', label='control points')
plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y'); plt.legend();
```

[image: periodic tri pulse]